# Null pointer exception in Map<Set<Node>,String>>

Tags: java

I checked the values before finding.....all the values were assigned
    but I'm getting nullpointer exception....can any one tell me how to iterate through map if this is wrong?

```
static String findtheregion(Map<Set<Node>, String> rtn1,Node node) 
        {
            Set<Set<Node>> ls=rtn1.keySet();
            Iterator<Set<Node>> it=ls.iterator();
            String str;
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                Set<Node> sn=it.next();
                if(sn.contains(node)){
                    str=rtn1.get(sn);
                return str;}
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: its resulting null value for str when returning....thats the problem..im getting nullpointer exception in another function

Comment: Please give us a stack trace so we can help you. Without seeing the data you passed in, and no stack trace, it's mighty difficult to help.

Comment: So, in other words, this function is returning null. That's probably happening because a match isn't being found.

Comment: If the method returns null, perhaps the node wasn't found. Include the code where values are inserted.

Comment: @user864408: It makes a big difference that a `NullPointerException` is being thrown in *another function* instead of in this one. It would have been more helpful if you had included that information in your original question.

Comment: Thanks all...I got the it...I just passed the wrong parameters....

Answer (score 1):

**Update in response to your comment on your question**:

If your `NullPointerException` is due to null being **returned** from this function, then the issue is clearly that no matching `Set` is being found.

Does your `Node` object have a correct implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`?  Most `Set` implementations (especially `HashSet`) will fail to work if your `equals()` and `hashCode()` are broken or not defined.

**Original answer**:

Is there a reason why you aren't using the new enhanced `for` syntax?

It looks like what you're trying to do is:

```
static String findTheRegion(Map<Set<Node>, String> rtn1, Node node) {
    for (Map.Entry<Set<Node>, String> entry : rtn1.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().contains(node)) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't see any obvious place for a `NullPointerException` to occur, but I can easily see problems with this code if your `Set<Node>` is mutable.  If the set changes while it's being used as a key, it will almost certainly invalidate the invariants of the `Map` implementation being used, which could produce a `NullPointerException`.

Also, your data structure does not make sense for the operation you're trying to do.  Should you perhaps be using a [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) instead?